# Rails Backbone Coffeescript clear Interval from function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

How to clear my all Intervals from my current function "hp_added()"? OR better, how to prevent this function from calling twice ? I need this almost allways to be called, and once, but it is called by many other functions and increases counting more and more everytime. Cant find in internet clear solution.

```
  window.delay = (ms, fn)-> setTimeout(fn, ms)
  window.timer = (ms, fn)-> setInterval(fn, ms)

  hp_added: ->
    if @model.attributes.player_hp < @model.attributes.max_hp
      @hp_adding()

  hp_adding: ->
    self = this
    if Interval?
      clearInterval this.hp_adding()   //its not working
    timer 2000, ()-> self.model.set(player_hp: self.model.attributes.player_hp+1) and self.model.save() if self.model.attributes.player_hp < self.model.attributes.max_hp
```

I found a solution for me, its working allways and i need to call it only once at the beginning. Maybe somoene knows better solution?

```
  initialize: ->
    @hp_ad()

  hp_ad: ->
    alfas = "true"
    if alfas is "true"
      @hp_added()
      alfas = "false"

  hp_added: ->
    self = this
    timer 3000, ()-> self.hp_adding()

  hp_adding: ->
    if @model.attributes.player_hp < @model.attributes.max_hp
      @model.set(player_hp: @model.attributes.player_hp+1)
      @model.save()
```

Comment: What is `Interval`? Wouldn't that be infinite recursion if `Interval?` was true?

Comment: Actually i dont know exactly what it does, i just see its repeating itself and i tryed to stop it.

Comment: The thing you hand to `clearInterval` is the interval ID that `setInterval` returns so `clearInterval this.hp_adding()` doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to stop a running `setInterval` in order to start a new one?